# If $\sin^4(\alpha)+ 4\cos^4(\beta) +2 =4\sqrt{2} \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin^4(\alpha)+ 4\cos^4(\beta) +2 =4\sqrt{2} \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)$

And $\alpha,\beta \in [0,\pi]$

Then find
$\cos(\alpha+\beta)-cos(\alpha-\beta)$

I know that $\cos(\alpha+\beta)-cos(\alpha-\beta) = -2\sin\alpha\sin\beta$

But I don't know how to bring it in the equation
I tried multiple formulas and tried to bring to same power but couldn't get an answer

Can someone try?

Is there any other method other than using $AM \geq GM$

Can anyone explain through completing square method?

Comment: Hint: AM-GM $$\sin^4 \alpha+4\cos^4 \beta +1+1\ge 4\sqrt{2}\sin \alpha \cos \beta$$ when does equality occur?

Comment: Is there any other way to do this apart from $ AM  \geq GM$

Comment: $$a^4+b^4+2-4\sqrt2ab=(a^2-2b^2)^2+2(\sqrt2a^2b^2-1)^2$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate?